# Meaning of 'x days ago' on Disqus Discovery widget

Tags: disqus

Below is a screenshot from [this example post](http://tshepang.net/1st-floss-patch-contribution):

[image]

If you scroll to the bottom, and do not have some ad-block software blocking Disqus Discovery, you will note that the links on the left have date labels, like *3 days ago*. What do those mean, since they definitely have nothing to do with when the posts were published (as you can tell my visiting them)?

I could not find info on this on [the official product page](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/666278).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This refers to the date that the thread was created in the Disqus system. The Disqus thread being loaded for "Cube" has a createdAt timestamp of "2013-05-10T17:37:29" despite listing a post timestamp of 2013-02-10

Just to recap, a thread is created when the page is first visited when the Disqus embed is loaded. In cases of websites that just added Disqus, this is almost guaranteed to not match the actual post's timestamp. However, future threads should be very close.

You'll also notice that the timestamp is only used when there are no comments on the thread, so this wouldn't be visible on actively-commented websites.